# How to order table view cell from newest to oldest instead of from oldest to newest

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am making a Notes app using with Xcode in Swift 3. I have a way to add notes, a way to save, delete, and title notes. When I make notes, they are listed from oldest to newest like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K59R.png

Here is my code:

```
//
//  ListNotesTableViewController.swift
//  NotesApp
//
//  Created by on 6/22/17.
//  Copyright © 2016. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ListNotesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var notes = [Note](){
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        notes = CoreDataHelper.retrieveNotes()
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return notes.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listNotesTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ListNotesTableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        let note = notes[row]
        cell.noteTitleLabel.text = note.title
        cell.noteModificationTimeLabel.text = note.modificationTime?.convertToString()
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            CoreDataHelper.delete(note: notes[indexPath.row])
            notes = CoreDataHelper.retrieveNotes()
        }
    }
    @IBAction func unwindToListNotesViewController(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
        self.notes = CoreDataHelper.retrieveNotes()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier {
            if identifier == "displayNote" {
                print("Table view cell tapped")
                let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
                let note = notes[indexPath.row]
                let displayNoteViewController = segue.destination as! DisplayNoteViewController
                displayNoteViewController.note = note
            } else if identifier == "addNote" {
                print("+ button tapped")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is located (I think, but I'm not sure) near the bottom. I wish I could be more specific on where the problem is, but then I would be able to solve this problem myself. This is my 3rd day with this language and I am very confused.

Anyways, how can I change the ordering of order in which the notes are displayed from Newest/Last Modified to Oldest/First Modified?

Edit: Here is the code for the CoreDataHelper:

```
//
//  CoreDataHelper.swift
//  NotesApp
//
//  Created by on 6/22/17.
//  Copyright © 2017. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit

class CoreDataHelper {
    static let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    static let persistentContainer = appDelegate.persistentContainer
    static let managedContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
    static func newNote() -> Note {
        let note = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Note", into: managedContext) as! Note
        return note
    }
    static func saveNote() {
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save \(error)")
        }
    }
    static func delete(note: Note) {
        managedContext.delete(note)
        saveNote()
    }
    static func retrieveNotes() -> [Note] {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Note>(entityName: "Note")
        do {
            let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return results
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error)")
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to sort your `notes` array as needed.

Comment: Probably best to sort them in your CoreDataHelper.retrieveNotes method. What does that look like?

Comment: What does that mean? (Sorry for my complete lack of knowledge... :/)

Comment: I will post my CoreDataHelper file above... There. Done.

Comment: @Octavius Ca you show your core data structure for `Note` entity or the class `Note`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as others have mentioned is not the table. You have to provide your data in order and since you're getting it from coredata it's fairly easy

```
static func retrieveNotes() -> [Note] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Note>(entityName: "Note")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"date", ascending: true)] //date would be whatever theKeyWhereYouStoreTheDateInYourDatabaseIs
    do {
        let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return results
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error)")
    }
    return []
}
```